# Можно ли задавать вопросы с вариантами ответов?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Недавно проходил тест в одной из компаний, и по некоторым заданиям у меня возникли вопросы. При этом, некоторые из этих задний содержат варианты ответов. Стоит ли задавать на SO вопросы с вариантами ответов, или же лучше их генерализировать? Я бы, конечно, хотел оставить их "как есть", так как мне интересно именно "почему то, а не это".

[Пример вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579895/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85)

Comment: а вы сами знаете какой из вариантов правильный?

Comment: @Grundy нет, поэтому у меня и возникли вопросы :)

Comment: Имхо, знание «почему этот вариант правильный и в каких случаях правильный не этот, а другой» куда полезнее, чем просто «какой вариант правильный».

Comment: @NickVolynkin вот этим как раз я и интересуюсь. И поэтому хочу эти варианты опубликовать в своих вопросах, чтобы подробно каждый вариант "разжевать"

Comment: @NickVolynkin это уже будет затрагивать ответ, но сначала надо выяснить позицию по вопросу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет. Ответы следует в форму ответов помещать. Но это не ваш случай (ситуация в теле вопроса отличается от его заголовка).

Сам вариант решения НЕ является ответом на вопрос **«почему»** его следует выбрать по сравнению с другими вариантами. Поэтому можно задавать вопрос: *«есть задача, есть **рабочие** варианты решения. Какой вариант предпочесть в **таком-то** случае и **почему**?»*

Если вы не укажите **«таком-то»** часть, то ваш вопрос вероятно слишком обширным будет (если нужно книжку написать, чтобы достаточно деталей упомянуть, то такой ответ вне рамок Stack Overflow).

Если не все представленные варианты являются **рабочими** для заданной задачи, то лучше задать вопрос о задаче в целом (если не знаете как её решать) или задать отдельный вопрос о *конкретном* выбранном варианте, который вы не понимаете когда следует использовать. Упоминание нерабочих решений, которые вы сами не создали и не знаете почему они нерабочие—не очень полезно для будущих читателей, но можно привести в конце вопроса для контекста.

Обратите внимание что вопросы:

- Как сделать `X`?
- `A`, `B` являются решениями для `X`. Есть ли и какие *объективные* критерии (основанные на фактах и опыте работы, а не личном вкусе) по которым `A` предпочтительней чем `B` в моём случае `Y`?
- Почему `C` не работает для `X`?

являются *разными*.

Если у вас вопрос *"как сделать X?"*, то не следует помещать `A`, `B` в сам вопрос, если вас устраивает как они решают задачу. Если не устраивает, то можно их привести в самом вопросе и указать что именно не нравится и какими свойствами желаемый ответ должен обладать (в этом случае ни `A` ни `B` не являются ответом).

Comment: Похоже, я не совсем явно задал вопрос. Я имел в виду вопросы вида: "Что из `A`, `B`, `C` является решением для задачи `X` и почему?". При этом подразумевается, что правильный (утверждённый) ответ должен включать подтверждение (либо опровержение) того, что `A`, `B` и `C` является решением для `X`, а не просто "`B` является решением `X` потому, что..." с польным игнорированием двух других пунктов.

Comment: @Виктор: как я уже сказал: *"Если не все представленные варианты являются рабочими для заданной задачи, то лучше задать вопрос о задаче в целом"* а A, B, C в конце для контекста добавить (если это поможет на вопрос ответить, если нет, то задайте *несколько* вопросов: 1- "как сделать X" без искусственных ограничений, которые полезность вопроса уменьшают 2- *после* того как вы уже знаете как сделать X, то более сфокусированный вопрос про варианты, "почему", итд—не обязательно про все варианты). См. ["Работа за автора"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

Comment: `Как сделать X?` В правилах же написано, что нельзя задавать вопросы с несколькими вариантами ответа.